# HTML5 Drag & Drop Paragraph from Button

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have the following code (slightly modified from http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

I modified it to work with `<p>` elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .div 
        {
            width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev)
        {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="div" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Code</p>
    <p id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Code</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there are basically two boxes that you can drag paragraphs within. My question is that how would I go about dragging a paragraph from a button? I am actually working on this for a mobile app and I am wondering how I can have it so that the user drags a paragraph from the button to the page. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what you mean that,paragraph from a button?

Comment: @Manoj In its current state, you drag a paragraph and it ends up as a paragraph. I want it so that you drag a button to a page, except instead of it ending up as a button, it changes to the paragraph as you are dragging it. I hope it is clear what I am trying to do - it is very hard to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know at how much extend i understand your problem, i think you can try below code

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/mWCA9/)**

**JS** :

```
  function allowDrop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev)
        {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.innerHTML+=" <p>"+document.getElementById(data).innerHTML+"</p>";

        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I needed. Just changed the code a bit to use jQuery and it works perfectly.